# 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'Hight'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to use some data so I changed the row's name with

> df.rename

and I got  a right  resultat with the changes but when I'm trying to use the name of the new row I got this name

> DataFrame' object has no attribute 'Hight'

this is my code :

```
x=data['Time Series (Daily)']
df = pd.DataFrame(x)
df=df.rename(index={'2. high':'Hight','3. low':'Low'})
df['h+l']=df.Hight + df.Low
```

Comment: look up how to use `.loc` and `.iloc`

Comment: I'm also guessing here, but if you're doing time series, you'd probably want your rows/index to be your time, and then have the columns of low and high. then you could create a 3rd column that sums your low and high columns

Comment: You need to put the DataFrame Structure and  and desired output here and the what you attempted that will help to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

```
df = df.rename(index={'2. high':'Hight','3. low':'Low'})
df.loc['h+l'] = df.loc['Hight'] + df.loc['Low']
```

Example input:

```
                a         b
2. high  0.007900  0.000021
3. low   0.010771  0.000033
```

Output:

```
              a         b
Hight  0.007900  0.000021
Low    0.010771  0.000033
h+l    0.018671  0.000054
```

If on the contrary you work with `columns`, then you can do in this way:

Input:

```
    2. high    3. low
0  0.007900  0.000021
1  0.010771  0.000033

df = df.rename(columns={'2. high':'Hight','3. low':'Low'})
df['h+l'] = df['Hight'] + df['Low']
```

Output:

```
      Hight       Low       h+l
0  0.007900  0.000021  0.007921
1  0.010771  0.000033  0.010803
```